# if-statement doesn't work in for-loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an issue with the if-statement and need some help. This is a short code-snippet in html:

```
          {% for category in categories %}
            {% if category == 'christmas' %}
            <p>{{category}} 1</p>
            {% else %}
            <p>{{category}} 2</p>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
```

With the for-loop I walk through ca[tegories and check them with an if-statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WST4w.jpg) for the string 'christmas'. The paragraph is always the second one, ending with a 2. Still, it appears that the category with the name 'christmas' comes up. That means, that in the if-statement "category" is different than in the p-tag. In fact, category is empty in the if-statement.

Why? Can someone help here, please. Thanks!

Edit: Added two pictures. On the right you see the output:

[length is zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WST4w.jpg)
[showing no fit, although it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9s8z.jpg)

Comment: Have you got leading/trailing spaces for the category and is it all lowercase? If `categories` is a model of some sort - do you mean to be accessing an element of `.name` or `.title` or something and what you're seeing is the `__str__` you defined in the model?

Comment: What does `categories` contains ? Are you sure it is really a list of str objects ? If not, `category == 'christmas'` statement will always evaluate to False, and the loop will always print "<category> 2"

Comment: Can you please post the (a) `categories` variable, (b) the output you obtain, (c) the output you intended? Right now it is quite chaotic.

Comment: Is `categories` a list of strings or a queryset of something like `Category` model instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looping over category objects from a model meaning `categories` is not a list of strings but a queryset? In that case you should do something like this:

```
      {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.name == 'christmas' %}
        <p>{{category}} 1</p>
        {% else %}
        <p>{{category}} 2</p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

Replace `.name` by whatever your correct attribute is.

Your `{{category}}` is probably displayed correctly because of your `__unicode__` or `__str__` method.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, it worked out! I just had some brain-issues here... The category field wasn't called name, category. So category.category was the way.